# back button exits app instead of going to previous activity

Tags: android

I have a number of activities setup from registration to login etc but when I click the back button on my android phone, it exits the app whereas I would like it to go to the previous activity. I have tried backpressed() but doesn't seem to work for me. At this stage, I won't be implementing a back arrow via the toolbar.

Could anyone assist me please? Code is below for one of my activities.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_gradient_orange"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_full_name"
            android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:id="@+id/cardView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/logIn"
                android:textSize="20dp" />



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/employerEmailAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="#FAFAFA"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/email_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/employerEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/employerPassword"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="#FAFAFA"
                    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/password_icon"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/employerPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Log in"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_gradient_orange"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/haveAccount"
            android:textColor="#999"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/signUpMessage"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my java code - very simple activity for the example.

```
package com.example.dennis.discover;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.nfc.Tag;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.WindowManager;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class EmployerLogIn extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView haveAccount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_employer_log_in);


    haveAccount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.haveAccount);

    haveAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent employerSignUp = new Intent(EmployerLogIn.this, 
   EmployerSignUp.class);
            startActivity(employerSignUp);
            finish();
            }
        });

     }
 }
```

Comment: Do not finish activity if u want keep them alive

Answer (score 0):

remove `finish()` after `startActivity(employerSignUp);`

Comment: Please add some context as to why this solves the problem

Comment: finish() method finishes the current activity. When you finish your EmployerLogIn to open EmployerSignUp, there won't be any activity back stack. If you just start new activity without using finish(), the current activity will go in pause state and new activity will sit on top of it